# EF Core 3 - Simple 'Where' Query throwing Error?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-functions

I've built a small Http Azure Function which queries a database. I'm doing a query like so...

```
var item = await DbContext.Items
                          .Where(x => x.ItemId == itemId && x.IsActive)
                          .ToListAsync();
```

Now when I do this it throws an error:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Test. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore: The LINQ expression 'DbSet
> [2020-10-15T20:56:40.424]     .Where(r => r.ItemId== __itemId_0 && r.IsActive == True)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Once I remove the `&&` and make it querying a singular property then it works. I've looked at other posts where they get the same error message but they're using more complex operations in their queries. Here, it's simple and I know it can be done as the Entity Framework Core documentation even uses an example such as this. I've also tried using `ToListAsync()` on the `IQueryable` and still nothing. `FirstOrDefault()`, `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` have also both been tried.

Here is my DbContext...

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>
{
    #region DbSets 

    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and here is my item entity...

```
public class Item
{
    #region Column Definitions

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Show your entity and DbContext definitions please.

Comment: Updated question with them in

Comment: What can I say. It should work. Maybe some converters fail.
I suggest to create small reproducible sample and post an issue to EF Core repository.

Comment: Have you tried change your query to the following format? `DbContext.Items.Where(x => x.ItemId == itemId).Where(x => x.IsActive == true).ToListAsync();`

Comment: https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/60504903/csharp-linq-expression-could-not-be-translated - check this out.